# How to check if a section in MVC Core configuration file exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I check if a specific section in loaded ASP.NET Core configuration file exist?

I have a JSON configuration file that I load it in `Startup` class via `ConfigurationBuilder.AddJsonFile` method.

This JSON file is an array with this layout:

```
{
   "Url": "",
   "Regex": [ "", "" ],
   "Keys": {
     "Title": "",
     "Description": "",
     "Keywords": [ "" ]
   }
}
```

But some of them doesn't have `Keys`. I tried to check return type of `section.GetSection("Keys")` against `null`, But it doesn't return `null` even if `Keys` section isn't present.

Comment: Did you tried `Configuration.GetSection("Keys")`?

Comment: @Sanket I iterate on the array and read every element  into `section` var. I tried `section.GetSection("Keys")` but it return an object whose it's inner properties or sections are `null` not itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `GetChildren` method:

```
var keysExists = Configuration.GetChildren().Any(x => x.Key == "Keys"));
```

Answer (score 8):

Also it is possible to use use Exists extension method from Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions. Exapmle:

```
var section = Configuration.GetSection("Keys")
var sectionExists = section.Exists();
```

or

```
public bool IsExistsConfigurationSection(string sectionKey)
{
    return Configuration.GetSection(sectionKey).Exists();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use `ConfigurationExtensions.Exists(IConfigurationSection)` method as [Алексей Сидоров suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49105628/1844247) because this method as it's said in [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationextensions.exists?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_ConfigurationExtensions_Exists_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfigurationSection_)

> determines whether the section has a Value or has children

Not only children.

Here are my extension methods with checking section existence which might be helpful for someone.

Usage:

```
_configRoot.GetSectionChecked(nameof(Site));
// instead of 
// IConfigurationSection section = _configRoot.GetSection(nameof(Site));
// if (!section.Exists())
//     throw new ArgumentException(nameof(Site));

services.ConfigureSection<Site>(_configRoot);
// instead of 
// services.Configure<Site>("Site", _config);

services.ConfigureSection<PostsConfig>(_configRoot.GetSection(nameof(Site)), nameof(Site.Posts));
// instead of 
// services.Configure<PostsConfig>(_configRoot.GetSection(nameof(Site)).GetSection(nameof(Site.Posts)));
```

Extension methods:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;

public static class ConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static IConfigurationSection GetSectionChecked(this IConfiguration config, string sectionName)
    {
        var section = config.GetSection(sectionName);
        CheckSection(section);
        return section;
    }

    public static IServiceCollection ConfigureSection<TOptions>(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config, string sectionName = null) 
        where TOptions : class
    {
        string typeName = sectionName ?? typeof(TOptions).Name;
        IConfigurationSection section = config.GetSectionChecked(typeName);
        return services.Configure<TOptions>(section);
    }

    public static IServiceCollection ConfigureSection<TOptions>(this IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationSection section, string sectionName = null)
        where TOptions : class
    {
        CheckSection(section);
        return services.ConfigureSection<TOptions>((IConfiguration)section, sectionName);
    }

    private static void CheckSection(IConfigurationSection section)
    {
        if (!section.Exists())
            throw new ArgumentException($"Configuration section '{section.Path}' doesn't exist.");
    }
}
```