# How to know if a Key exists on IConfiguration

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, configuration

I have

```
IConfiguration cfg;
string keyName;
```

Will `cfg.GetSection(keyName)` tell me whether the key exists inside cfg ?

I just **need to know if the key (keyName) exists.**
I don't care about its value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a section in MVC Core configuration file exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41606148/how-to-check-if-a-section-in-mvc-core-configuration-file-exist) As well as [How to check if Configuration Section exists in .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641488/how-to-check-if-configuration-section-exists-in-net-core)