# Find if Key that has a null value exists in IConfiguration

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, configuration

I have:

```
IConfiguration cfg;
string key;
```

I must detect if the `key` exists inside `cfg` when the key has a **'null'** value.

I know the key is inside, I see it with the debugger, but I need a method to detect that.

I thought that `cfg.GetSection(key).Exists()` would return True. 
But it always returns **False**.

According to documentation, `cfg.GetSection(key)` **never** returns null, even if key doesn't exist, so it is of no help.

Comment: Didn't you ask the same [How to know if a Key exists on IConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61779244/how-to-know-if-a-key-exists-on-iconfiguration) already?

Comment: I did ask - but there the answer was to use the ```Exists()``` method - but it doesn't work if the value is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `cfg.AsEnumerable()` to get the keys that are inside the configuration.
You can log and see them:

```
foreach (var kv in cfg.AsEnumerable()) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", kv.Key, kv.Value);
}
```

**=>** So all you need to do is just find if the specific key you are looking for is in this IEnumerable.

```
var keyNames = cfg.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

if (keyNames.ContainsKey(keyName))
{
    keyExistsInConfiguration = true;
}
```